# UserControl containing nested Grids, and exposing Content property of deepest nested grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

I want to create a custom usercontrol that contains two grids nested inside of each other:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
...

public class VGrid : Grid
{
    public VGrid()
    {
        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
        { Height = GridLength.Auto });

        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
        { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
        { Height = GridLength.Auto });
    }
}

public class HGrid : Grid
{
    public HGrid()
    {
        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
        { Width = GridLength.Auto });

        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
        { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});

        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
        { Width = GridLength.Auto });

    }
}
```

Here's where I get stuck... How to create custom properties for each row,column of inner and outer grid that assigns the corresponding children with correct attached property of row/column of the grid.

```
public class NineGrid : HGrid
{
    VGrid inner0;
    VGrid inner1;
    VGrid inner2;

    public NineGrid()
    {
        inner1 = new VGrid();
        inner2 = new VGrid();
        inner3 = new VGrid();

        this.Children.Add(inner1);
        this.Children.Add(inner2);
        this.Children.Add(inner3);
    }
}
```

But, here's what I want it to look like:

```
<local:NineGrid>

    <!-- First Row: Toolbar + Hamburger Button -->
    <local:NineGrid.XY_0_0><Button Content="0,0"/><local:NineGrid.XY_0_0>
    <local:NineGrid.XY_0_1><Button Content="0,1"/><local:NineGrid.XY_0_1>
    <local:NineGrid.XY_0_2><Button Content="0,2"/><local:NineGrid.XY_0_2>

    <!-- Second Row: ContentPage + Left and Right Side Menus -->
    <local:NineGrid.XY_1_0><Frame Name="AFrame0"/><local:NineGrid.XY_1_0>
    <local:NineGrid.XY_1_1><Frame Name="AFrame1"/><local:NineGrid.XY_1_1>
    <local:NineGrid.XY_1_2><Frame Name="AFrame2"/><local:NineGrid.XY_1_2>

    <!-- Third Row: Status Bar + Misc + Settings Button -->
    <local:NineGrid.XY_2_0><Button Content="2,0"/><local:NineGrid.XY_2_0>
    <local:NineGrid.XY_2_1><Button Content="2,1"/><local:NineGrid.XY_2_1>
    <local:NineGrid.XY_2_2><Button Content="2,2"/><local:NineGrid.XY_2_2>

</local:NineGrid>
```

Using a button in the XAML example is a toy example of how i would use this custom control.

The real scenerio is first row, a command bar with left and right controls that appear and disappear based on size of window or menu state,   second row with center content with left and right popout menus, last row with a status line.

Is it Possible?  Its just that normal XAML code gets confusing if you nest two grids inside of each other, and then put more content in it that also contains  grids.. so my idea was to create a custom control that flattens the two top-level nested grid into one control that is already setup the way i want it, for 95% of the cases that i need.  The problem is how to populate this custom control of nested grids using XAML.

Comment: Why don't you use a single Grid with 3 rows *and* 3 columns? That said, it should be pretty clear that with nesting you would either need 1 outer VGrid and 3 inner HGrids or the other way round, 1 HGrid and 3 VGrids.

Comment: ContentPropertyAttribute Class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.contentpropertyattribute  I'm thinking it should be a class that inherits from a grid, and then in the constructor creates a new grid and assigns it to the Child of this.grid, then does some magic with ContentPropertAttribute to assign the new grid's children property of the inner grid instead of the default of the outer grid's children

Comment: Is this something you would reuse over and over? Or just one page?

Comment: Use at least once per page.  However, It might be interesting to nest a NineGrid inside of one of the Cells of a NineGrid a well...

Comment: @BillMoore Do you need the HGrid and VGrid for more than the NineGrid?

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is just nesting VGrid and HGrid and forgetting about merging them:

```
<Page
    x:Class="junk6.BlankPage2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:junk6"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <local:VGrid>
        <local:HGrid Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Button0"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Button1"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Button2"/>
        </local:HGrid>

        <local:HGrid Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Buttonc0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Buttonc1" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Buttonc2"  
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </local:HGrid>


        <local:HGrid Grid.Row="2">
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Button0"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Button1" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Button2"/>
        </local:HGrid>

    </local:VGrid>

</Page>


using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace junk6
{

public class VGrid : Grid
{
    public VGrid()
    {
        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
        { Height = GridLength.Auto });

        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
        { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
        { Height = GridLength.Auto });
    }
}

public class HGrid : Grid
{
    public HGrid()
    {
        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
        { Width = GridLength.Auto });

        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
        { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});

        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
        { Width = GridLength.Auto });

    }
}

}
```

Also Possible to nest it the other way around:

```
<Page
    x:Class="junk6.BlankPage3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:junk6"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <local:HGrid>
        <local:VGrid Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Button0"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button1"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Button2"/>
        </local:VGrid>

        <local:VGrid Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Buttonc0" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Buttonc1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Buttonc2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </local:VGrid>


        <local:VGrid Grid.Column="2">
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Button0"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button1" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Button2"/>
        </local:VGrid>

    </local:HGrid>

</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace GridNineExperiment
{

public class VGrid : Grid
    {
        public VGrid()
        {
            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
            { Height = GridLength.Auto });

            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
            { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
            { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        }
    }

    public class HGrid : Grid
    {
        public HGrid()
        {
            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
            { Width = GridLength.Auto });

            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
            { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
            { Width = GridLength.Auto });

        }
    }

    //================================================================
    // NineGrid
    //================================================================
    public class NineGrid : VGrid
    {
        public HGrid inner0;
        public HGrid inner1;
        public HGrid inner2;

        public NineGrid()
        {
            inner0 = new HGrid();
            inner1 = new HGrid();
            inner2 = new HGrid();

            this.Children.Add(inner0);
            this.Children.Add(inner1);
            this.Children.Add(inner2);

            Grid.SetRow(inner1, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(inner1, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(inner2, 2);
        }

        //===========================================================
        // (0, 0)
        //===========================================================
        private FrameworkElement private_NG00 = null;

        public  FrameworkElement NG00
        {
            get { return private_NG00; }
            set {
                inner0.Children.Add(value);
                Grid.SetColumn(value, 0);
                private_NG00 = value;
            }
        }

        //===========================================================
        // (0, 1)
        //===========================================================
        private FrameworkElement private_NG01 = null;

        public FrameworkElement NG01
        {
            get { return private_NG01; }
            set
            {
                inner0.Children.Add(value);
                Grid.SetColumn(value, 1);
                private_NG01 = value;
            }
        }

        //===========================================================
        // (0, 2)
        //===========================================================
        private FrameworkElement private_NG02 = null;

        public FrameworkElement NG02
        {
            get { return private_NG02; }
            set
            {
                inner0.Children.Add(value);
                Grid.SetColumn(value, 2);
                private_NG02 = value;
            }
        }

        //===========================================================
        // (1, 0)
        //===========================================================
        private FrameworkElement private_NG10 = null;

        public FrameworkElement NG10
        {
            get { return private_NG10; }
            set
            {
                inner1.Children.Add(value);
                Grid.SetColumn(value, 0);
                private_NG10 = value;
            }
        }

        //===========================================================
        // (1, 1)
        //===========================================================
        private FrameworkElement private_NG11 = null;

        public FrameworkElement NG11
        {
            get { return private_NG11; }
            set
            {
                inner1.Children.Add(value);
                Grid.SetColumn(value, 1);
                private_NG11 = value;
            }
        }

        //===========================================================
        // (1, 2)
        //===========================================================
        private FrameworkElement private_NG12 = null;

        public FrameworkElement NG12
        {
            get { return private_NG12; }
            set
            {
                inner1.Children.Add(value);
                Grid.SetColumn(value, 2);
                private_NG12 = value;
            }
        }

        //===========================================================
        // (2, 0)
        //===========================================================
        private FrameworkElement private_NG20 = null;

        public FrameworkElement NG20
        {
            get { return private_NG20; }
            set
            {
                inner2.Children.Add(value);
                Grid.SetColumn(value, 0);
                private_NG20 = value;
            }
        }

        //===========================================================
        // (2, 1)
        //===========================================================
        private FrameworkElement private_NG21 = null;

        public FrameworkElement NG21
        {
            get { return private_NG21; }
            set
            {
                inner2.Children.Add(value);
                Grid.SetColumn(value, 1);
                private_NG21 = value;
            }
        }

        //===========================================================
        // (2, 2)
        //===========================================================
        private FrameworkElement private_NG22 = null;

        public FrameworkElement NG22
        {
            get { return private_NG22; }
            set
            {
                inner2.Children.Add(value);
                Grid.SetColumn(value, 2);
                private_NG22 = value;
            }
        }

    } // Class

}


<Page
    x:Class="GridNineExperiment.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GridNineExperiment"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <local:NineGrid>

        <!-- ROW 0-->
        <local:NineGrid.NG00>
            <Button Content="Button0"/>
        </local:NineGrid.NG00>

        <local:NineGrid.NG01>
            <Button Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </local:NineGrid.NG01>

        <local:NineGrid.NG02>
            <Button Content="Button2"/>
        </local:NineGrid.NG02>

        <!-- ROW 1-->
        <local:NineGrid.NG10>
            <Button Content="Buttonc0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </local:NineGrid.NG10>

        <local:NineGrid.NG11>
            <Button Content="Buttonc1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </local:NineGrid.NG11>

        <local:NineGrid.NG12>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Buttonc2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </local:NineGrid.NG12>

        <!-- ROW 2-->
        <local:NineGrid.NG20>
            <Button Content="Button0"/>
        </local:NineGrid.NG20>

        <local:NineGrid.NG21>
            <Button Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </local:NineGrid.NG21>

        <local:NineGrid.NG22>
            <Button Content="Button2"/>
        </local:NineGrid.NG22>
    </local:NineGrid>
</Page>
```